# Double sum depending only on sum of arguments

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

Lets suppose  i have a sum of the type

$$\sum_{a=a_{\mathrm{min}}}^{a_{\mathrm{max}}}\sum_{b=b_{\mathrm{min}}}^{b_{\mathrm{max}}}f(a+b)$$

where $f$ is some well-defined function. I would like to rewrite the sum as a sum over the argument $M:=a+b$. What I have so far:

$$\sum_{a=a_{\mathrm{min}}}^{a_{\mathrm{max}}}\sum_{M=b_{\mathrm{min}}+a}^{b_{\mathrm{max}}+a}f(M)$$

Is it possible to write this is a sum over $M$ from $a_{\mathrm{min}}+b_{\mathrm{min}}$ to $a_{\mathrm{max}}+b_{\mathrm{max}}$, by introducing some factor in front of $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. So you can do something like
$$\sum _{\substack{x+y=M\\a_{min}\leq x\leq a_{max}\\b_{min}\leq y\leq b_{max}}}f(M)=\sum _{M = a_{min}+b_{min}}^{a_{max}+b_{max}}\#\{\text{Ways }x+y=M\text{ with restrictions}\}\cdot f(M),$$
notice that if $x=i$ with $a_{min}\leq i\leq a_{max}$ then you want $b_{min}\leq M-i\leq b_{max}$ and so you want $M-b_{max}\leq i\leq M-b_{min}$ so you want $\max \{a_{min},M-b_{max}\}\leq i\leq \min \{a_{max},M-b_{min}\}$ and there are $\min \{a_{max},M-b_{min}\}-\max \{a_{min},M-b_{max}\}+1$ integers in between that. So
$$\sum _{M = a_{min}+b_{min}}^{a_{max}+b_{max}}\left (\min \{a_{max},M-b_{min}\}-\max \{a_{min},M-b_{max}\}+1\right )\cdot f(M)$$

Answer (score 0):

It would seem more fruitful to introduce $m=a+b$ in an outer sum. One can enforce the condition $m=a+b$ via an Iverson symbol $[\![m=a+b]\!]=\delta_{m,a+b}$ and then simplify:
$$
\sum_{a=a_\min}^{a_\max}\sum_{b=b_\min}^{b_\max}f(a+b)
=\sum_{m=a_\min+b_\min}^{a_\max+b_\max}\sum_{a=a_\min}^{a_\max}\sum_{b=b_\min}^{b_\max}[\![m=a+b]\!]f(m) \\
=\sum_{m=a_\min+b_\min}^{a_\max+b_\max}f(m)(\sum_{a=a_\min}^{a_\max}[\![b_\min\leq m-a\leq b_\max]\!]) \\
=\sum_{m=a_\min+b_\min}^{a_\max+b_\max}f(m)(\sum_{a\in\Bbb Z}[\![\max(a_\min,m-b_\max)\leq a\leq \min(a_\max,m-b_\min)]\!])
 \\
=\sum_{m=a_\min+b_\min}^{a_\max+b_\max}f(m)\bigl(\min(a_\max,m-b_\min)+1-\max(a_\min,m-b_\max)\bigr).$$
Here the final parenthesised expression is a positive integer that varies as follows as $m$ increases: it increases from $1$ by unit steps, then (possibly) remains constant, and finally decreases by unit steps to $1$; the values separating these regimes are $a_\max+b_\min$ and $a_\min+b_\max$; either of them may come first, and if they are equal the middle regime disappears (reduces to length $0$).